# How to use setSaveFormData Api in android 8 for WebView

Tags: android, webview

When using the setSaveFormData() Api in WebSettings in Android 8, I got the message below:

`Sets whether the WebView should save form data. In Android O, the platform has implemented a fully functional Autofill feature to store form data. Therefore, the Webview form data save feature is disabled. Note that the feature will continue to be supported on older versions of Android as before. This function does not have any effect.`

It says Android O will Autofill, but when I submit a form in Android 8's webview, It doesn't work. How to saveFormData In android 8 ?

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. From skimming the [Autofill framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill) documentation it doesn't seem like there's an easy way to do this in a WebView, if it is even possible at all. However I don't want to throw the towel in yet.

Comment: check this https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AutofillFramework/issues/13